# In Kotlin, can an interface be derived from a custom class?

Tags: kotlin, interface, superclass, derived-class

I just started learning Kotlin and came across the following snippet while going through the documentation:

```
internal class LifecycleObserver : MyLocationListener(
    private val context: Context,
    private val lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    private val callback: (Location) -> Unit)
```

This came from https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#kotlin, about halfway down the page (just in case I left out something vital to understanding the context of this example). `LifeCycleObserver` is an interface while `MyLocationListener` is a user-defined class, and assuming that that's the case, it appears to me that the tutorial writer has derived an interface from a user-defined class. Is this something that's even possible? If so what's the name of this technique/set of techniques? If not...well, the same question still applies. With the correct terminology in hand, my research can be a lot more productive than it has been the past few days. Thanks for reading.

Comment: `LifeCycleObserver is an interface` looking at the snippet you posted, it's not an interface, it's a class. Classes can inherit from classes and interfaces, but interfaces can only inherit from other interfaces.

Comment: I do agree with you actually; my confusion mainly comes from the website I linked to since  `LifecycleObserver` is the name of an interface (androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver), and the site this snippet came from is speaking about this existing interface every other time the name is used. Why would the writer use `LifecycleObserver`? Or rather is there a point to this choice that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I visited the [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#lco) you mentioned. Actually it is a mistake in their kotlin code. When you switch to java code, you can see that class is defined as,

```
class MyLocationListener implements LifecycleObserver {
    private boolean enabled = false;
    public MyLocationListener(Context context, Lifecycle lifecycle, Callback callback) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Its corresponding kotlin code would be,

```
internal class MyLocationListener(
    private val context: Context,
    private val lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    private val callback: (Location) -> Unit
) : LifecycleObserver {
    private var enabled = false
    ...
}
```

But somehow an error sneaked in and LifecycleObserver came before ':' and MyLocationListner gone after ':'. If you can, just report that error to them.

And as you know already, an interface cannot be derived from a class.